# How much data does inputstream.read reads in java

Tags: java, inputstream

I was looking at the definition of the read method of inputstream object, I am confused about how much data is read everytime since it says "reads some bytes"

```
public int read(byte[] b)
         throws IOException
Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.
```

Lets say i have a buffer array of size 200 and the data in the inputstream is 100 bytes. Is it guaranteed that inputStream.read gets all 100 bytes ?

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of this interface (or to be precise: abstract class): you can **absolutely not** rely on *assuming* how many bytes were read. You **always always always** have to check the return value of that method to know.

Background: there are many different implementations for this interface. Some my buffer, some may not. Some read "fixed" input (maybe from existing data in memory). Somebody might decide to give you a stream that turns to the internet, download a 10 GB file and then start sending you one byte after the other.

The only thing you know is: the method returns

> the total number of bytes read into the buffer

End of story.

Comment: And yes, 17 years ago I got that wrong. I had code reading data from a socket. And the first thing to read was a 4 byte header. You know, its just 4 bytes. Why on earth should it return less than 4 bytes. I assumed that I would always get 4 bytes. But in 0.1% of all cases, I got only 2 or 3 bytes. It took me 4 weeks of debugging and going crazy before finding that bug.

Answer (score 1):

While *nothing* is guaranteed when reading from an `InputStream` and concrete implementations (see the `throws IOException` part), yes, if you have a buffer whose size is larger than the data read, all data should be read into the buffer, and the remaining `byte`s in the buffer will not be written, hence staying at default primitive value of `0`.

This is also a caveat when piping from an `InputStream` to, say, an `OutputStream`.

The `read` method returns the number of `byte`s read or `-1` when the stream ends.

This gives you an indication of *how much* of your buffer you need to write for an "exact copy".

Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])).

Answer (score 1):

[InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) is an *abstract class* (not an "object"). As such, it only specifies an *interface*, not an *implementation*, so implementation details depend on the actual nonabstract subclass you use.

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no guarentee. `read(byte b[])` simply delegates to the `read` method that takes three parameters [`read(byte b[], int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-) like so:

```
return read(b, 0, b.length);
```

The documentation for that method reads as follows:

> Reads **up to len bytes** of data from the input stream into an array
>   of bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but **a
>   smaller number may be read**. The number of bytes actually read is
>   returned as an integer.